# AsyncFileUpload, can't refresh page after upload is completed

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I have an Ajax AsyncFileUpload on one of my pages (inside a update panel). The control works, however I want the page to reload after the upload is complete. I tried a `Response.Redirect` in the code behind for the OnUploadedComplete method and a `location.reload(true)` in the OnClientUploadComplete. Both result in javascript alert of `Server Response Error: 'Unknown Server error'

Do you want to see the response page?` and the page doesn't refresh.

Has anyone been able to do a full page refresh after the upload has completed?

Edit: I mistakenly said the AsyncFileUpload is in a control panel, I meant to say update panel.

Comment: @peroija-Have you tried by giving the ID as "Client ID".

Comment: Why you don't use asp:FileUpload instead?

Comment: @DotNetter can you please elaborate what you are suggesting I give the client ID to?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy I originally tried a normal file upload but it doesn't work in an update panel

Comment: @peroija-You need to add client ID to the ID of upload control as I had the same problem before and got worked when I changed to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `asp:FileUpload` control and register it as postback control with Scriptmanager's `RegisterPostBackControl` method. Or add postback trigger entry for this FileUpload to Triggers collection of UpdatePanel

Comment: not fully a correct answer, but you got me to try this control again. `asp:FileUpload` can't be used as a trigger because it doesn't have a click event. however, a separate upload button does. I was able to use a `Response.Redirect()' at the end of the button's click event to refresh the page like i wanted. Not sure why none of this worked when I originally tried it :P 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This control panel that you told. Is this a UpdatePanel? If it is, you can try an upd.Update(); to refresh the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Becareful, if you have Response on your backside you may be ending your page's life cycle right there.  This is just a guess.  Check to make sure that your code is even reaching the intended point. Look for things like Response.End which will will prevent anything thereafter from executing.